# Developing Cordova + Ionic in Android Studio [Ionic Serve]

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework

I'm new in developing with Ionic. I want to develop for android devices. I have loaded the android folder below in Android Studio and started developing. From there I can easily run the application on my connected device. But for developing a bit more faster, i want to develop in browser. When I navigate to the project with CMD and execute `ionic serve` i always get the "Ionic Blank Starter" Page. I guess he is accessing on the www folder in main root, but how I can execute the project under platforms/android in browser?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to

http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/testing.html

```
$ cordova prepare android
```

want to help you.

Comment: Didn't helped, this just added a new android project within my ionic project. I want only test my application, which im developing for android in a browser.

Comment: Have you considered using this?
[link](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-app-ripple-simulator/)

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem, and in the end I was forced to move/overwrite www folder from android to the root of Ionic project. Then 'ionic serve' will work. If you will need to launch Android; run 'cordova prepare android' as was mentioned before. Do it with attention - 'prepare android' will overwrite old android project and its www folder.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic runs within the file structure which is created by itself.

The content in platforms is generated (and ovewrited) by ionic when you run `ionic serve` based on the contents on `www` folder and the files in the root project folder.

I still don't know a way to get an actually app built from Android Studio and convert to ionic, it will be a good find.